# What are the valid provisioning states for an Azure Deployment

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-resource-group

I am writing some automation using the azure java sdk that takes action depending on the provisioning state of an Azure Template Deployment. However, I do not know all the valid values for the provisioning state.

Specifically in the azure java sdk provisioningState is just a String.

```
package com.microsoft.azure.management.resources

public interface Deployment extends
    Indexable,
    Refreshable<Deployment>,
    Updatable<Deployment.Update>,
    HasInner<DeploymentExtendedInner>,
    HasManager<ResourceManager>,
    HasName {
  /**
   * @return the state of the provisioning process of the resources being deployed
   */
  String provisioningState();
}
```

I suspect this is because different services have different Deployment implementations and different `ProvisioningState` classes.

Which `ProvisioningState` class should I look at to determine the valid states for an Azure Template deployment?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.management.websites.models.provisioningstate

Answer (score 4, accepted):

May be you could refer to [`ProvisioningState Class`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/com.microsoft.azure.management.containerregistry._provisioning_state?view=azure-java-stable).

> **Fields**
>
> CANCELED, CREATING, DELETING, FAILED, SUCCEEDED, UPDATING

Inheritance `java.lang.Object`->`ExpandableStringEnum<T>`->`ProvisioningState`. And the `ExpandableStringEnum<T>` class belongs to `com.microsoft.azure.management.resources.fluentcore.arm`.

Comment: Thanks this is what I needed.

Comment: Actually, not correct.  `Accepted`, `Created`, `Running` are apparently also allowed values.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.management.websites.models.provisioningstate

Answer (score 1):

There used to be a ProvisioningState Enum in the azure-mgmt-resources SDK (<1.0.0) but it is not the case in the latest versions.
Anyways, it is a good indicator to get started:
https://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.microsoft.azure/azure-mgmt-resources/0.9.8/com/microsoft/azure/management/resources/models/ProvisioningState.html

Answer (score 1):

`ProvisioningState`: `Canceled`, `Deleting`, `Failed`, `InProgress`, `Succeeded`

https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.management.websites.models.provisioningstate